# The number of ways to paint a red tile in a grid.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

here's the question:

"You have nine tiles arranged into a three by three square mosaic. If you color each tile red or blue with equal probability, what is the probability that there exists a two by two square of red tiles in this mosaic? The other tiles touching the two by two square can be red or blue and there still exists a square."

I think I might have struck upon an answer, but I would need help verifying as I don't know how to check myself.

I started by considering a 2x2 mosaic, with at least one red tile. There are $2^4$ possible mosaic patterns, 15 of which obviously have at least one red (the only exception is the entirely blue pattern). But I looked at it differently: I chose one tile to be red, and then figured out the number of patterns that could be had from picking other tiles from the three remaining undecided tiles to paint red: $\binom{3}{0} + \binom{3}{1} + \binom{3}{2} + \binom{3}{3} =  8$. Then I considered the next tile of the four, and the cases where I decided to paint it red. Because all cases involving the first tile I chose have been exhausted, I have less options: $\binom{2}{0} + \binom{2}{1} +\binom{2}{2} = 4$. I then repeated for the third tile: $\binom{1}{0} + \binom{1}{1} = 2$ and the last tile: $\binom{0}{0} = 1$. Adding all of these possibilities gives $8 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 15$. So the total probability is $\frac{15}{16}$.

Now, it was easy to see I was correct there, but when it comes to painting the 2x2 square of tiles, I'm not sure if my method would still hold up. There are four possible ways to paint the 2x2 square in the mosaic. I start by painting the square in the first position, and then accounting for all arrangements of the remaining five tiles: $\binom{5}{0} + \binom{5}{1} + \binom{5}{2} + \binom{5}{3} + \binom{5}{4} + \binom{5}{5} = 32$. Then I moved onto considering the second square, which has lost two potential tiles that were accounted for in the cases where the previous square covered them: $\binom{3}{0} + \binom{3}{1} + \binom{3}{2} + \binom{3}{3} = 8$. Then the third square, which has again lost two possible tiles: $\binom{1}{0} + \binom{1}{1} = 2$. I think the last square has already been completely accounted for here, so the total probability is $\frac{42}{2^9}= \frac{21}{256}$.

Could someone help me out if I'm wrong, or help me confirm if I'm correct in my method?

Thanks.

Comment: I have not gone through your calculation in detail, so cannot point to issues. The answer is not right, by quite a bit.

Comment: Can't follow your method so can't comment, but I got the answer $\frac{95}{512}$.

Comment: Could you explain how you got that answer, @David? It might help me find where my own proof went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A_{nw}$ be the event that the "north-west" $2\times2$ block is red, and so on.  By inclusion/exclusion the required probability is
$$\eqalign{P(A_{nw}\cup A_{ne}\cup A_{se}\cup A_{sw})
  &=P(A_{nw})+\cdots\cr
  &\qquad{}-P(A_{nw}\cap A_{ne})-\cdots\cr
  &\qquad{}+P(A_{nw}\cap A_{ne}\cap A_{se})+\cdots\cr
  &\qquad{}-P(A_{nw}\cap A_{ne}\cap A_{se}\cap A_{sw})\ .\cr}$$
Now for $A_{nw}$ to occur, $4$ squares must be red and we don't care about the rest.  So $P(A_{nw})=\frac{1}{2^4}$.  For $A_{nw}\cap A_{se}$ to occur, $7$ specific squares must be red and we don't care about the other $2$ (if you can't see why this is so, draw a diagram), so $P(A_{nw}\cap A_{se})=\frac1{2^7}$.  I'm sure you can do the rest for yourself.

Comment: Thanks, this makes it so much clearer than my horrendous piece-wise method...I missed so many cases doing it my way. It still boggles my mind getting over the step where we can say we only care about six/seven tiles being red...I would think this included possible arrangements of the square where we formed shapes which didn't include 2x2 squares? Like an H?

Comment: I don't mean any old $7$ squares - have added one more word to my answer - see if that clears things up.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I can see how the two would be the same anyways.